# Alternative to itertools.compress()?

Tags: python

```
import itertools
  
  
ListA =['1', '2', '3', '4']
ListB = [None, None, 0, 1]
```

I have the two lists; I need to basically do itertools.compress(), but only None values don't count, so the "0" would be the same as the 1.

Comment: Create `ListC = [x is not None for x in ListB]`. Then use that with `itertools.compress()`

Comment: @Peter Wood So what would it look like?

Comment: Use filter `[i[0] for i in filter(lambda x: (x[1] or x[1]==0), zip(ListA, ListB))]` here you can define custom filtering you want.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`itertools.compress`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) documentation tells you the implementation:

```
def compress(data, selectors):
    # compress('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1]) --> A C E F
    return (d for d, s in zip(data, selectors) if s)
```

This can be adjusted to only compress `None` like so:

```
>>> [d for d, s in zip(ListA, ListB) if s is not None]
>>> ['3', '4']
```

Alternatively, as @Barmar commented, you can use `compress` but perform an intermediate loop to convert the selectors into the truth values you want:

```
>>> compress(ListA, (e is not None for e in ListB))
>>> ('3', '4')
```

This is probably a superior solution.